# Запуск celery на сервере

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, supervisord

я новичок в программировании, и у меня возникла проблема с запуском celery на продакшен сервере. Использую nginx, rabbitmq, celery, django 2 и uwsgi. В файле
(пример) 
supervisor.conf :

```
[program:uwsgi]
user = www-data
directory = /path/to/project
command = uwsgi --emperor /path/to/vassals --uid www-data --gid www-data
autostart = true
autorestart = true
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/site_uwsgi_err.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/site_uwsgi_out.log
stopsignal = QUIT
```

Запуская celery в командой:
(пример)

```
>>> celery -A myproject worker -l info
```

Все работает замечательно, пока не отключусь от сервера. 
Вот и собственно вопрос, каким образом можно добавить celery в запуск supervisor или сделать чтобы все работало. 
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Таким же, как вы добавили uWSGI. Хотите чтобы конфигурацию написали за вас и не пришлось читать документацию?

Comment: Спасибо. Я не прошу написать за меня, Я прошу сказать, в какую сторону двигаться, потому что читал документацию и celery и supervisor и пробовал делать по разным туториалам, но успеха не принесло. Поэтому и обратился сюда, с мыслю что помогут с решением или подскажут в какую сторону копать.

Comment: "Успеха не принесло" - это очень общее определение. Под ним скрываются конкретные ошибки или нештатное поведение систем. Вот их и надо предметно разбирать. Сначала попытаться самому, а если за несколько дней упорных попыток не получилось, то создавать вопрос с подробным описанием ошибки и выполненных вами безрезультатных действий.